# ¿Cómo puedo completar la fecha en una lista y agregar Nan en otra lista?

Tags: python

Hola amigos de Stack Over Flow, tengo las siguientes listas:

```
lista_a=['2009-09-15','2009-09-17','2009-09-20','2009-09-25']
lista_b=[-0.56,1.53,2.65,0.34]
for i in lista_a:
    for x in lista_b:
        if i==x:
            print(i)
```

Como ven cada fecha está alineada con cada valor.

¿Como podría agregar las fechas faltantes en la lista_a y rellenar con Nan en las posiciones faltantes de la lista_b?

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué has intentado hacer? Recuerda que las preguntas sin un esfuerzo por parte del usuario suelen ser cerradas y/o votadas negativamente

Comment: También vi que tienes muchas preguntas que han recibido respuesta y no has aceptado, por favor lee la sección [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y procesa las preguntas que has hecho, si tienen respuestas válidas entonces acéptalas, si tienen respuestas que no solucionan tu problema entonces agrega un comentario explicando lo que hace falta

Comment: La respuesta a esta pregunta es muy sencilla, cuando agregues el código que has intentado utilizar y proceses tus preguntas anteriores te publico la respuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Para hacerlo únicamente necesitas [`pandas.DataFrame.asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html), el pre-requisito es que el índice debe ser una serie de tiempo

Utilizando tus datos como ejemplo y convirtiendo el índice a `datetime`

```
import pandas as pd

lista_a=['2009-09-15','2009-09-17','2009-09-20','2009-09-25']
lista_b=[-0.56,1.53,2.65,0.34]

df = pd.DataFrame({'valor': lista_b}, index=lista_a)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Obtenemos el siguiente `dataframe`

|  | valor |
| --- | --- |
| 2009-09-15 00:00:00 | -0.56 |
| 2009-09-17 00:00:00 | 1.53 |
| 2009-09-20 00:00:00 | 2.65 |
| 2009-09-25 00:00:00 | 0.34 |

Luego utilizamos `asfreq()` que tomará la fecha y hora inicial y final y rellenará con la frequencia que definamos

```
df = df.asfreq(freq='D')
```

**Nota:** Se pueden llenar más datos que el primero y/o último obtenido del `dataframe`, por favor revisa la documentación para más información al respecto

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`

|  | valor |
| --- | --- |
| 2009-09-15 00:00:00 | -0.56 |
| 2009-09-16 00:00:00 | nan |
| 2009-09-17 00:00:00 | 1.53 |
| 2009-09-18 00:00:00 | nan |
| 2009-09-19 00:00:00 | nan |
| 2009-09-20 00:00:00 | 2.65 |
| 2009-09-21 00:00:00 | nan |
| 2009-09-22 00:00:00 | nan |
| 2009-09-23 00:00:00 | nan |
| 2009-09-24 00:00:00 | nan |
| 2009-09-25 00:00:00 | 0.34 |

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado

Comment: No hay de qué, saludos!